# Can i enable Alt + Tab when a key is pressed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey, hotkeys, alt-tab

I need to have the ability to turn Alt + Tab on and off. Is there a way to do that via AHK. I know how to disable it but reverse that is not possible i think.

I disable it user `!Tab::Return`

Comment: I added it is there a way to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm). In general you can use it to conditionally run some code. A straightforward idea is to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or nothing, depending on some condition.

But since sending <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> [is troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35971730/10765659), you want rather [`AltTab`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabDetail) more than any alternative. The problem is:

> `AltTab` and `ShiftAltTab` are two of the special commands that are only recognized when used on the same line as a hotkey.

They are not recognized inside the `If` statement.

Fortunately there is also [`#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm):

> `#If` is positional: it affects all hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath it in the script. […] To turn off context sensitivity, specify `#If` […] but omit all the parameters.

This way we can conditionally apply your known way to disable the key and we don't even need `AltTab` in the script:

```
#If (GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T"))
   !Tab:: Return
   +!Tab:: Return   ; to disable Shift+Alt+Tab as well
#If
```

Now <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> is like "AltTabLock". It locks <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Adjust the condition to your needs. A variable may be useful. E.g. this will make <kbd>F10</kbd> the toggle key:

```
#If (disable==1)
   !Tab:: Return
   +!Tab:: Return
#If
F10:: disable:=NOT(disable)
```